# How can i uninstall ubuntu that installed to windows drive?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, grub2

I use monster abra a5 and today i have installed ubuntu 19.04 because the other ones were causing crushes. So i have installed it with using other option in the installation menu. After i have installed it computer started as windows and didn't ask me "do you want to start with linux or windows?". And the local disk that windows installed, almost full. Some folders belongs to ubuntu has installed to windows disk. I remove the spaces that i shrinked to install ubuntu on them before installation. But linux is using almost 30 gb in windows drive so how can i delete this linux residuals?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please note: 19.04 is past its End of Life, so should you decide to reinstall Ubuntu later, please use a currently supported version. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOL tells you what's supported here.

Comment: Suggest you visit our Windows Q&A site https://SuperUser.com since this is a Windows only question.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you did not specify where root ( " / " ) should go during installation, or [GRUB](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/grub.html) failed to write itself in as the default bootloader.

However, since Windows Boot Manager is still in charge, you may use [Windows Disk Manager](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/storage/disk-management/overview-of-disk-management) to delete the ext4 partition, and then give its space back to Windows.

Comment: Firstly thank you for your reply but i had specified an unallocated space before installation and specified where root, home and swap area but not efi only. I deleted all other partition except windows but problem is in windows disk. I looked the file sizes in the disk although the file sizes in disk seems 100 gb, disk has 108 gb. 8 gb gone somewhere but i can not find.